# UIScrollview Inside a tableview scrolling issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a tableview with 10 sections and each section has a scrollview in UITableviewcell.

Situation-->
Scrollview is not scrollable and tableview is scrolling up/down.

Problem-->
When user start scrolling on inside scrollview , tableview does not scrolls or listens to scrolling.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


NSString *identifier = @"CellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell* result = [_tblMainTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

result = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:identifier];

CGRect frame = [_tblMainTable rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"Main row height : %f", frame.size.height);
[result setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, mainWidth, frame.size.height)];
result.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

CGFloat popHeight=frame.size.height-100;
//show and hide rows here
UIView *uvContentView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, mainWidth, frame.size.height)];
//UIView *uvContentView=[[UIView alloc] init];
[result addSubview:uvContentView];

if ([[dictIndexPaths valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.section]] isEqualToString:@"YES"])
{
    uvContentView.hidden=YES;
    //imgSelectedCellImage=@"plus.png";

}else{
    uvContentView.hidden=NO;
    //imgSelectedCellImage=@"minus.png";
    UIView *popView=[utility createView:0 forY:0 forW:mainWidth forH:180 backColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


    if (indexPath.section==0) {
        NSLog(@"contact Table Height %f\n ContentView Height %f",frame.size.height,uvContentView.frame.size.height);
        objContactInfo.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, mainWidth, uvContentView.frame.size.height);
        objContactInfo.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        objContactInfo.formId=formId;
        [uvContentView addSubview:objContactInfo];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:0 forY:290 forW:mainWidth forH:20 backColor:[UIColor blackColor]]];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:0 forY:345 forW:mainWidth forH:20 backColor:[UIColor blackColor]]];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:mainCenter forY:180 forW:mainWidth-mainCenter forH:110 backColor:[UIColor blackColor]]];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:mainCenter forY:740 forW:mainWidth-mainCenter forH:140 backColor:[UIColor blackColor]]];

        [uvContentView addSubview:popView];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section==1){

        //objBasisDesc.center=CGPointMake(0, 61);
        objBasisDesc.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, mainWidth, uvContentView.frame.size.height);
        objBasisDesc.formId=formId;
        [uvContentView addSubview:objBasisDesc];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:mainCenter forY:0 forW:mainWidth-mainCenter forH:135 backColor:[UIColor clearColor]]];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:mainCenter forY:190 forW:mainWidth-mainCenter forH:715 backColor:[UIColor clearColor]]];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section==2){
        objAdressProp.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, mainWidth, uvContentView.frame.size.height);
        objAdressProp.formId=formId;
        [uvContentView addSubview:objAdressProp];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:mainCenter forY:0 forW:mainWidth-mainCenter forH:160 backColor:[UIColor clearColor]]];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:mainCenter forY:215 forW:mainWidth-mainCenter forH:165 backColor:[UIColor clearColor]]];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section==3){
        objNameOfPerson.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, mainWidth, uvContentView.frame.size.height);
        objNameOfPerson.formId=formId;
        [uvContentView addSubview:objNameOfPerson];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:mainCenter forY:0 forW:mainWidth-mainCenter forH:260 backColor:[UIColor clearColor]]];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section==4){
        objWitness.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, mainWidth, uvContentView.frame.size.height);
        objWitness.formId=formId;
        [uvContentView addSubview:objWitness];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:mainCenter forY:0 forW:mainWidth-mainCenter forH:260 backColor:[UIColor clearColor]]];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:0 forY:590 forW:mainWidth forH:20 backColor:[UIColor clearColor]]];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section==5){
        objTypeofHouse.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, mainWidth, uvContentView.frame.size.height);
        objTypeofHouse.formId=formId;
        [uvContentView addSubview:objTypeofHouse];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:mainCenter forY:0 forW:mainWidth-mainCenter forH:310 backColor:[UIColor clearColor]]];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:mainCenter forY:420 forW:mainWidth-mainCenter forH:450 backColor:[UIColor clearColor]]];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section==6){
        objComplaintSum.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, mainWidth, uvContentView.frame.size.height);
        objComplaintSum.formId=formId;
        [uvContentView addSubview:objComplaintSum];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:0 forY:0 forW:mainWidth forH:177 backColor:[UIColor clearColor]]];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section==7){
        objRelatedQues.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, mainWidth, uvContentView.frame.size.height);
        objRelatedQues.formId=formId;
        [uvContentView addSubview:objRelatedQues];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:mainCenter forY:0 forW:mainWidth-mainCenter forH:640 backColor:[UIColor clearColor]]];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section==8){
        popHeight=popHeight-50;
        objSignDate.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, mainWidth, uvContentView.frame.size.height);
        objSignDate.formId=formId;
        [uvContentView addSubview:objSignDate];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:0 forY:0 forW:mainWidth forH:112 backColor:[UIColor clearColor]]];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:mainCenter forY:0 forW:mainWidth-mainCenter forH:312 backColor:[UIColor clearColor]]];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section==9){
        objLearnedAbout.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, mainWidth, uvContentView.frame.size.height);
        objLearnedAbout.formId=formId;
        [uvContentView addSubview:objLearnedAbout];
        [uvContentView addSubview:[utility createView:mainCenter forY:0 forW:mainWidth-mainCenter forH:360 backColor:[UIColor clearColor]]];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section==10){
        objPhotoOrVideoVC.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, mainWidth, uvContentView.frame.size.height);
        [uvContentView addSubview:objPhotoOrVideoVC];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section==11){
        //objNameOfPerson.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, mainWidth, uvContentView.frame.size.height);
        //[uvContentView addSubview:objNameOfPerson];
    }

}




    // result.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        return result;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the xib's as tablecell in uitableview.Make these xib's freeform and set the height of table cell according to xib's height.